# Pandas Python, estou tendo problema em descobri qual loja vendeu mais no ultimo mes

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tenho problema para saber como faço para pegar o ultimo mes que no caso e o mes 2018/02 para pode tira a media de quem vendeu mais nesse mes.

```
import pandas as pd
% matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('store_data.csv')
df.tail()

    week    storeA  storeB  storeC  storeD  storeE
195 2018-01-28  282 6351    7759    5558    1028
196 2018-02-04  4853    6503    4187    5956    1458
197 2018-02-11  9202    3677    4540    6186    243
198 2018-02-18  3512    7511    4151    5596    3501
199 2018-02-25  7560    6904    3569    5045    2585

df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'])
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 200 entries, 0 to 199
Data columns (total 6 columns):
week      200 non-null datetime64[ns]
storeA    200 non-null int64
storeB    200 non-null int64
storeC    200 non-null int64
storeD    200 non-null int64
storeE    200 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(5)
memory usage: 9.5 KB
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, tudo bem?

Fiz da seguinte forma, coletei apenas os valores que você mostrou, sendo 4 datas de fevereiro e 1 de janeiro.

[image: Dataframe]

Então, faço a comparação da seguinte forma em data com tipo "datetime64[ns]" que é seu caso.

```
filtro = ((df['week'] > 'data_inicio') &
     (df['week'] < 'data_fim'))
```

No dataframe acima para selecionar apenas fevereiro ficaria:

```
filtro = ((df['week'] > '2018-01-30') &
     (df['week'] < '2018-03-01'))
```

E então, crio um novo dataframe com este filtro:

```
novodf = df.loc[filtro]
```

Onde visualizando, percebemos que ele só trouxe as datas do mês 2:

[image: Dataframe filtrado]

Para retirar a média da maneira mais simples, aplico uma função do pandas nas colunas do novo dataframe:

```
novodf.mean()
```

Resultando:

[image: Media final]

Existem formas mais bonitas de apresentar este dado, porem acho que isto já te da uma luz em como aplicar filtro de data no pandas.

Abraço.

Claudio